# How to simulate a mouse click and drag using javascript with XY Coords

Tags: javascript, simulation, mouse

How to simulate a mouse click and drag using javascript with XY Coords

I know how to click using XY coords

document.elementFromPoint(100, 100).click(); - for example

this works perfectly

but I need something that can drag my mouse between two XY coords

Hope this makes sense

Comment: you might need to make a short case to describe why you aren't a duplicate of existing similar questions.

Comment: aint found anything helpful to use with XY coords